# How to make write a data frame to a csv file?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am making a data frame where one column is a major, and the second column is the list of courses in the major.

`df <- data.frame(majors = majors)
df[,"courses"] <- courses`

where majors is a vector and courses is a list of lists. When I try to write using

```
write.csv(df,"Majors_and_Courses.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I get an error saying "Error in write.table(df, "Majors_and_Courses.csv", row.names = FALSE,  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'"

Comment: You need to unlist the list.  `df[,"courses"] <- unlist(courses)`. The error is happing due to list data type is present in dataframe. the list can't be taken directly to csv.

Comment: unlisting at that point would change the length of the object - therefore, the join will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you were creating a data.table or similar, since `df[,"courses"] <- courses` would otherwise give you a warning.

**Solution using data.table:**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(majors = c("John", "Lisa", "Tim"))
courses <- list(a = list("m","n","o"), b = list("p", "q", "r"), c = list("s", "t", "u"))
dt[,"courses"] <- courses
dt$courses <- vapply(dt$courses, paste, collapse = "; ", character(1L))
write.csv(dt, "Majors_and_Courses.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Unlisting beforehand would change the length, unlisting after adding it to the data table would export the "c(...)" structure.
You can change the separator for the nested list the way you wish, but I discourage you to reuse the separator of the file that you are exporting ("," in this case) to avoid confusion.